# How to best setup Multi Module Gradle Java Project to make a public Java API to a proprietary Codebase?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am currently working on a Multi Module Gradle Java Project and want to expand the project to allow for a public Java API through which developers can add plugins to my core application (API), while my core code remains private (Core). The idea is similar to applications such as:

- The Minecraft Plugin Frameworks (PaperMC), where the actual Minecraft code remains hidden but the respective API is publicly accessible.
- Jenkins

I am trying to implement such a model for my own project with the following requirements:

1. Any code in Core must not be publicly accessible
2. When the API module is compiled it should not contain Core, but it has to be available to reference (So that I can ya know build the API)
3. Core should have access to API (So that I can integrate the API into the application)
4. The Core should have the API compiled into it so that any plugins that are injected can actually be correctly interpreted by the Core

If any of these requirements pose a fundamental flaw I can of course change the structure, the above is purely based on prior research.

Here is what I currently have, which is throwing a Circular dependency issue, because I am very clearly setting this up incorrectly.

Core:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.awesomedude'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:22.0.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
    implementation project(':API')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

API:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.awesomedude'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly project(':Core')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:22.0.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: How do you expect developers  to test their code if they only have the API module and no implementation?

Comment: As for circular dependency, why does API depend on core? The relationship is simply that API depends on nothing, and core depends on API

Comment: This probably sounds dumb, but I thought you would just place into the plugins folder of my application, from which any and all plugins are loaded.

Comment: Wait that makes sense, because the API is just a bunch of wrappers of the stuff that the Core has to be able to read

Comment: That doesn't sound dumb, but if they have your application installed on their machine (I didn't realise they did) then your core is not truly "private". Java bytecode is very easily reverse-engineered. The best you can do is apply obfuscation, but that's not going to prevent a determined person from doing whatever they want, it just slows them down.

Comment: I get that, it's more the idea behind it. Like legally speaking and whatnot the Core is my Intellectual Property redistribution is not allowed and the API is public non-obfuscated and such

Comment: In which case, what you want is a very standard project structure. The API module should ideally depend on almost nothing, and should consist mainly of interfaces. The core depends on that, as do your plugin authors.